# Parsing with substring returning wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have this query which tries to capture the last 11 characters excluding the semi colon at the end of the date(string). But when I run the script it returns value which is not included in the string, and im stuck for days.

Here's my query

```
  select TOP 2 a.ACCOUNT,a.GPSDATE, 
  SUBSTRING(b.smsmsg, LEN(b.smsmsg) - 10, 6) [KM2] 
  from TblGPSCur a 
  inner join GPRSIN b on a.ACCOUNT = b.SMSFR
 where exists(select * from GPRSIN b where b.SMSFR = a.ACCOUNT 
                 and b.smsdt between '2014-10-27 14:00:00' and '2014-10-27 14:49:54')
```

**THE RESULT IS THIS**

[image]

This is the top 2 data im trying to parse

[image]

The result should be 277511767.8

Can anyone tell me where I might be doing wrong on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You have your `SUBSTRING()` setup incorrectly, it should be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(b.smsmsg, LEN(b.smsmsg) - 11, 11)
```

As the starting position is `LEN(x) - 11`, and you want 11 characters after that point.

Alternately, you can use **[LEFT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177601.aspx)** and **[RIGHT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)**:

```
declare @SillyLongString as nvarchar(100) 
set @SillyLongString = '1234567890a;s.a.dpoiuytghjkmnbvfg,277511767.8;'

select left(right(@SillyLongString, 12),11)

-- outputs: 277511767.8
```

This selects the 12 right-most characters and then takes the first 11 characters from that string.

Adding to your query:

```
select TOP 2 a.ACCOUNT,a.GPSDATE, 
       left(right(b.smsmsg, 12),11) [KM2] ...
```

Comment: Hi Sir,  Thanks for the answer, How will I do this a trigger or a stroed procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RIGHT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177532.aspx) function of SQL like this -

```
SELECT TOP 2 a.ACCOUNT
    ,a.GPSDATE
    RIGHT(b.smsmsg, 11) [KM2]
FROM TblGPSCur a
INNER JOIN GPRSIN b ON a.ACCOUNT = b.SMSFR
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM GPRSIN b
        WHERE b.SMSFR = a.ACCOUNT
            AND b.smsdt BETWEEN '2014-10-27 14:00:00'
                AND '2014-10-27 14:49:54'
        )
```

Comment: Result is 8,21000006;   
Don't know where it got that answer but I think its doing something